# Delete Menu Items if sheets are deleted in Google Spreadsheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My onOpen() has a script that clears content inside dynamic sheets.

Each submenu name has the same name as the Sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Reset')
    .addItem("Meta","resetmetaFunction")
    .addItem("Snapchat","resetsnapFunction")  
    .addItem("TikTok","resettiktokFunction")
    .addItem("Twitter","resettwitterFunction")
    .addItem("Youtube","resetyoutubeFunction")  
    .addItem("Google","resetgoogleFunction")
    .addItem("LinkedIn","resetlinkedinFunction")  
    .addItem("Programmatic","resetprogrammaticFunction")        
    .addItem("Clear All","resetAll")   
    .addToUi();
}
```

I want those submenus to disappear if a specific sheet is removed.

For example, if the sheet "Snapchat" is removed, the submenu "Snapchat" should also be removed.

How can I execute this in Apps Script ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script.

```js
// If you want to dynamically change the custom menu when the sheet is deleted, please install OnChange trigger to `onChange` function.
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "REMOVE_GRID") { // or if (["REMOVE_GRID", "INSERT_GRID"].includes(e.changeType)) {
    onOpen(e);
  }
}

function onOpen(e) {
  // This is from your script.
  var obj = [
    { sheetName: "Meta", func: "resetmetaFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Snapchat", func: "resetsnapFunction" },
    { sheetName: "TikTok", func: "resettiktokFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Twitter", func: "resettwitterFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Youtube", func: "resetyoutubeFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Google", func: "resetgoogleFunction" },
    { sheetName: "LinkedIn", func: "resetlinkedinFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Programmatic", func: "resetprogrammaticFunction" },
    { sheetName: "Clear All", func: "resetAll" },
  ];
  var { source } = e;
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetObj = Object.fromEntries(source.getSheets().map(s => [s.getSheetName(), true]));
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reset');
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, func }) => {
    if (sheetObj[sheetName]) {
      menu.addItem(sheetName, func);
    }
  });
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

- In this script, when the Spreadsheet is opened, the custom menu is created using the current sheets.
- If you want to dynamically change the custom menu when the sheet is deleted, please install OnChange trigger to `onChange` function. By this, when you delete a sheet, `onChange` function is run, and `onOpen` is run, and the custom menu is updated using the current sheets.
- If you want to dynamically run the script when a sheet is deleted and inserted, please modify `(e.changeType == "REMOVE_GRID")` to `(["REMOVE_GRID", "INSERT_GRID"].includes(e.changeType))`.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hello Tanaike and thank you for your kind support. I am receiving the following error when trying to run : TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'source' of 'e' as it is undefined.

Here's the sample spreadsheet for your reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CZkEhAXxZk4XlESLyDxV2BarjpNfMQi-Ud-rizZFS9o/edit#gid=1167442640

Comment: the problem is not with your script. The problem is that my simple trigger is not launching and I am receiving this error :  Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)
    at [unknown function](Short Report:94:36)

I will open a new question

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. About your 1st issue of `I am receiving the following error when trying to run : TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'source' of 'e' as it is undefined.`, in this case, I think that the reason for your this issue is due to that you might directly run `onOpen` and `onChange`. Please reopen the Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Karim About your 2nd issue, when I saw your Spreadsheet, I found that you are declaring a lot of global variables using the methods for authorizing. I think that the reason for your this issue is due to this. Please be careful about your global variables. And, I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might be due to your 2nd issue. Unfortunately, when I remove your all scripts in your Google Apps Script project and copy and paste my proposed script, no error occurs. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Karim Unfortunately, it seems that the reason for your current issue is not my proposed script. But, I have an important point in your current script. When you create a script and you want to use the global variables together with the simple trigger, please be careful about the methods which cannot be used with the simple trigger. Because, when such a method is included in the global variables, the script executed by the simple trigger might not be able to be correctly worked. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance. Unfortunately, I don't know what "Global Variables" Mean, can we fix this ? Also, I have asked the new question regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745513/exception-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-driveapp-getfilebyid

Comment: I removed my question, because I think I understood what you mean. I will try to include the global variables inside my functions

Comment: you are correct 100% the problem was indeed from the global variables. thank you so much

Comment: I confirm that your script is now working 100% as intended. Thank you very much for your kind support.